# Easiest way to upgrade intellij 2018 -> 2019?

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

I'm on ubuntu 18.04, and I want to upgrade my intellij commmunity version.

I know I can go to the website and download the binaries manually, but I have githount account synced to my 2018 preferences and settings.

Thus, it would far more preferable if I could make the upgrade without actually deleting my 2018 version.

Is there any way to accomplish this? (I have not installed intellij via snap -- doing `sudo snap refresh intellij-idea-community` did not work)

Comment: I believe, when you run a new version of Idea, it suggests you to import settings from the previous version.

Answer (score 5):

A quick Google search came up with this relevant [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49825786/5759072). The accepted answer has the information you are looking for, particularly this part:

> If you make an upgrade to another major version then (during installation) your home directory is scanned and you will be asked whether you want to reuse existing settings from a previous version of IntelliJ IDEA. The settings are migrated if you agree (copied to a new version-specific directory).

You can find more information about updating IntelliJ in general [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/update.html).